# How to get previous element in foreach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array of :

```
const buttons = ["home","menu","contact"]
```

I iterate through buttons using `foreach`.

```
buttons.forEach(btn => {
    let button = document.getElementById(btn)
    button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        button.classList.add('selected')
    })
});
```

As you can see i have added a classlist for each button using eventlistener. But i want to remove classlist of previous button when clicked other button.

Thank you!

Comment: If is always going to be the previous button?? So they are not going to click home first and contact second?

Comment: consider using a `for` loop instead

Comment: You really want the previous element or the previously clicked element? It looks like a query question more than a loop question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click one button then other button classList will be removed.
Here is the code.

```js
const buttons = ["home", "menu", "contact"]

buttons.forEach((btn, index) => {
  let button = document.getElementById(btn)
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    buttons.forEach(btnA => {
      document.getElementById(btnA).classList.remove("selected");
    })
    button.classList.add("selected");
  })
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="home">Home</button>
<button id="menu">Menu</button>
<button id="contact">Contact</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer when I posted mine, which was essentially the same (other than the addition of a snippet). I've converted your code to a snippet too. So given I wrote the same thing, it's obviously a good answer :) allow me to give you your first upvote.

Comment: That worked. The index parameter seems useless, right?

Answer (score 1):

See `Parameters` section [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp)

```
buttons.forEach((btn, index, arr) => {
  const previous = index > 0 ? arr[index-1] : null;
  
  let button = document.getElementById(btn)
  button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    button.classList.add('selected')
  })
});
```

Or you can use `pairwise` helper method e.g.

```
function pairwise<T>(array: Array<T>): Array<[T, T]> {
  return array.map((item, i, arr) => {
    if (i < arr.length) {
      return [arr[i], arr[i + 1]]
    }
  }).slice(0, -1);
}
```

This will transform given array to pairs e.g.

```
[1, 2, 3] => [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! but how do i add a classlist.remove() to the previous selected button.

Comment: This solution allows you to get previous button (in array sense). You didn't write it explicitly but you wanted previous selected button. I see there i already answer for that.